# How can I import a string file into a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, file-io, python-3.3

Basically I have a text file:

```
-1  2  0  
 0  0  0  
 0  2 -1  
-1 -2  0   
 0 -2  2   
 0  1  0
```

Which I want to be put into a list of lists so it looks like:

```
[[-1,2,0],[0,0,0],[0,2,-1],[-1,-2,0],[0,-2,2],[0,1,0]]
```

I have this code so far but it produces a list of strings within lists.

```
import os  
f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/example board.txt"))  
for line in f:  
    for i in line:  
        line = line.strip()  
        line = line.replace(' ',',')  
        line = line.replace(',,',',')  
        print(i)
        print(line)  
    b.append([line])
```

That produces `[['-1,2,0'],['0,0,0'],['0,2,-1'],['-1,-2,0'],['0,-2,2'],['0,1,0']]`
Which is almost what I want except with the quotation marks.

Comment: You're _printing_ something that _looks_ like a list of lists, you're not actually _creating_ a list of lists. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: No, I want it to behave like a list of lists. I need to reference each element in the list in the next part of my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution with no additional libraries

```
import os

lines = []
f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/example board.txt"))
for line in f:
    x = [int(s) for s in line.split()]
    lines.append(x)
```

Output:

```
[[-1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 2, -1], [-1, -2, 0], [0, -2, 2], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Good, but you should use the with statement

Comment: I'm actually quite surprised that `open("~/Desktop/example board.txt")`  worked-- wouldn't you need `os.path.expanduser`?

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, I need to practise list comprehensions a bit more. And I did have to import os and use os.path.expanduser

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend just using numpy for this rather than reinvent the wheel...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.loadtxt('example board.txt', dtype=int).tolist()
[[-1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 2, -1], [-1, -2, 0], [0, -2, 2], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Note: depending on your needs, you may well find a numpy array to be a more useful data structure than a list of lists.

Comment: When I try to import numpy it gives me the error: ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: Yep, because it is not included in python natively.  But don't let that scare you off, just install it!

Comment: I actually like this one better than mine. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

with open(r'example board.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    lines = list(reader)

print lines
```

Comment: You'd still need to convert the values in each field to integers.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid +1 I deleted mine in favor of this (However you should mention in Python 3 you want to use `open('data', newline='')` since OP may be using Py 3. Also open in binary read mode

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3.0 on a Mac, if that adds any clarity

Comment: I think this may have some difficulty with the multiple spaces.

Comment: Actually I think the file might be tab-delimited.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick since it appears that you want the data to be numbers and not strings:

```
fin = open('example.txt','r')
# The list we want
list_list = []
for line in fin:
    # Split the numbers that are separated by a space. Remove the CR+LF.
    numbers = line.replace("\n","").split(" ")
    # The first list
    list1 = []
    for digit in numbers:
        list1.append(int(digit))

    # The list within the list
    list_list.append(list1)

fin.close()
```

This produces an output like so:

```
[[-1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 2, -1], [-1, -2, 0], [0, -2, 2], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have comma separated values, the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module is frequently your best bet.  If that's not a good fit, for whatever reason, then here's a way to go about it with just the string and list built-ins.

You could do the whole thing in a list comprehension:

```
with open('~/Desktop/example board.txt', 'r') as fin:
    lines = [[int(column.strip()) for column in row.split(',')] for row in fin]
```

But that's opaque and could stand to be refactored:

```
def split_fields(row):
    fields = row.split(',')
    return [int(field.strip()) for field in fields]       

with open('~/Desktop/example board.txt', 'r') as fin:
    lines = [split_fields(row) for row in fin]
```